# Notification icon's size in custom expanded view is not the same as notification icon's size in normal view

Tags: android, notifications, android-custom-view, android-notifications

Suppose I have this layout for a custom notification:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="64dp" >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="64dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="64dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/app_icon"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:text="@string/update_apps_body"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

         <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/app_icon"
            android:layout_width="64dp"
            android:layout_height="64dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:src="@drawable/app_icon" />
    </RelativeLayout>        
      <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/btnUpdateAll"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/action_divider"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:foreground="@drawable/feature_button_selector" > 

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/update_all"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:drawablePadding="2dp"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/notif_update_all"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:text="@string/update_all" />
        </FrameLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I want to have notification icon in custom expanded view just like icon when using android big styles.

I set height and width of imageview with id=app_icon to 64dp so the icon size in expanded view is the same as icon size in normal view. I chose "64" according to [notification_template_big_base.xml](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/values/colors.xml) and [dimens.xml](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/6387d2f6dae27ba6e8481883325adad96d3010f4/core/res/res/values/dimens.xml). I tried to design app_icon just like imageview with id=icon in android source. It works fine. But in some devices, notification icon in expanded view becomes bigger than notification icon in normal view (so far I have seen this happen only in Samsung devices). Meanwhile if I use android expanded notification styles such as InboxStyle, everything is OK. I can't figure what's wrong with my layout design. I have added two screenshots to better illustrate what I mean. Notice the difference between red squares' sizes.[image: icon in normal view] [image: icon in expanded view]